# How to get URL of current website from Pimcore settings?

Tags: php, pimcore

We need generate links to thumbnails in CSV export in Pimcore.
From where to get the domain and protocol properly?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
since Pimcore provides a method to get Pimcore URL:

```
\Pimcore\Tool::getHostUrl($useProtocol = null, Request $request = null): string
```

Here are multiple samples how to use it:
https://hotexamples.com/examples/pimcore/Tool/getHostUrl/php-tool-gethosturl-method-examples.html